# script in rc.local is not executing on startup

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Im running rasbian jessi on a raspberry pi2b.

I inserted: `sudo usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg` into my `/etc/rc.local` file but nothing happens on startup. If I type /etc/rc.local into the terminal then my script runs fine. But on startup nothing happens.

I have tried

`sudo usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg` and

`sudo fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address

sudo fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg

_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
```

Comment: It is needless to use sudo in a system startup script, because all system startup scripts are executed by root.

Comment: Can you call `rc.local` interactively and is it doing what you want?

Comment: Yes, if I execute rc.local manually it works fine

Comment: Copy your `sh file` to `/etc/init.d/` and `update-rc.d your_script defaults` Be carefull on set your start and end point(meaning: When start, when stop ?).

Answer (score 0):

I didnt solve this but managed to get around it by using the init.d process instead of rc.local.

Explanation here:
[Run Script on Startup with Raspbian Jessi Wheezy and Raspberry Pi2b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162180/run-script-on-startup-with-raspbian-jessi-wheezy-and-raspberry-pi2b/35162470#35162470)

Answer (score 0):

I can show the png/jpg by fbi,here are my rc.local:

sleep 15
fbi -T 1 -a --noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/Logo.jpg &