# Run Script on Startup with Raspbian Jessi Wheezy and Raspberry Pi2b

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, startup, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I know there are lots of posts on this topic, but depite working through many many many of them I cant get this working.

I have a raspberry pi2b with raspbian jessie wheezy.

I want to run this framebuffer command automatically on startup:

`sudo /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg`

---

I initially edited rc.local and into it I tried each of these commands but nothing happened on startup:

`sudo /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg`

and

`sudo fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg`

---

so then I created a script called `script_auto_run` in my /home/pi/projects/test folder containing the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to start our application
sudo /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg
```

into rc.local I placed

```
sudo /home/pi/projects/test/script_auto_run
```

Again nothing happens on startup

---

So then I re-created my `script_auto_run` file in my `/etc/init.d` folder and its contents are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/script_auto_run
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          servoblaster
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example initscript
# Description:       This service is used to manage a servo
### END INIT INFO
sudo /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -t 1 -1 -a -noverbose /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg
exit 0
```

I ran the `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/script_auto_run` command and then edited my rc.local yet again to the following line:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/script_auto_run
```

---

None of these are working. I can run rc.local or script_auto_run from the terminal manually and there is no problem. But they are not executing automatically on startup. Raspbian is just booting to the GUI as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to follow this
http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/custom-boot-up-screen.
It works for me and it's easy.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I needed to create a link in `rc0.d` through `rc6.d` folders. Raspbian was looking in these folders to see what scripts needed to be run on startup and there was nothing telling it to run my script. I used the following command from the `/etc/init.d` folder where script_auto_run is located:

```
sudo update-rc.d script_auto_run defaults
```

I also required the `&` symbol in my script file so my script runs while rasbian continues to boot, otherwise the first image flashed up then the boot sequence just continued.

Always nice to figure it out...with a little help from my friend Google!